# Accessing Scope_Identity from controller with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I need to generate a value from whatever gets produced by a table's identity. The code is working, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do what I'm doing.

The issue is my controller is unaware of the Entity Framework, so I don't have direct access to the EF entity which will hold the identity value once the context has been saved.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(NewPlannerEntryCreateViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<PlannerEntryRecord, TradeSpendRecord>();

                //Need to insert the records, then update them so that I
                //can leverage existing stored procs
                TradeSpendRecord r = Mapper.Map<PlannerEntryRecord, TradeSpendRecord>(vm);
                r.VersionDate = now;
                _tsRepo.Insert(r);
                _uow.Save();
                _tsRepo.PostInsert();
                _uow.Save();


            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "US" });
        }
```

So I call my repo's insert method, which assigns the EF entity to a private field, then I call Save() on my context, which updates that EF entity, and then I call a PostInsert() method to generate my value:

```
 public class TradeSpendRepository : EFRepository<tblTradeSpend>, ITradeSpendRepository
{
    tblTradeSpend _record;

    public void Insert(TradeSpendRecord record)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<TradeSpendRecord, tblTradeSpend>();
        _record = Mapper.Map<TradeSpendRecord, tblTradeSpend>(record);

        base.Insert(_record);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// We need to access the identity of this record, which 
    /// we can only do after SaveChanges() is executed in the controller
    /// </summary>
    public void PostInsert()
    {
        //Build the promo id off the ID
        string promoId = (_record.ID + 1).ToString();
        promoId = "000000" + promoId;
        promoId = "P" + promoId.Substring(promoId.Length - 7, 7);
        _record.PromoID = promoId;
        Update(_record);
    }
```

Any way to clean this up?

Chris

Comment: Why do you have so many different classes to map between? `TradeSpendRecord` looks pretty redundant.

Comment: I removed some properties for clarity, but I'd rather my MVC controller be decoupled from the Entity Framework, so I've built out DTOs to transfer data from my EF repo to my controller.